# How to find some additional points on a line between two points in 3D?

Tags: c#, math, coordinates

Is there a function in C# which can give me all the points on a straight line between two points in 3D?

To calculate the distance between those two points, I use this:

```
public class Position {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
}

public void CalculateDistance(Position position1, Position position2, int mapId){
    float deltaX = position1.x - position2.x;
    float deltaY = position1.y - position2.y;
    float deltaZ = position1.z - position2.z;

    float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
    Console.WriteLine("Distance is: " + distance);
}
```

Example coordinates:

```
Position pos1 = new Position();
pos1.x = 141.6586f;
pos1.y = 0.6852107f;
pos1.z = 153.2231f; 

Position pos2 = new Position();
pos2.x = 142.336f;
pos2.y = 0.8685942f;
pos2.z = 130.8394f;
```

Let's say, the distance in line between those two 3d coordinates can be passed for 5 seconds. How can I print the current coordinate for every 1 second?

Comment: It's rather a mathematical problem than a programming one.

Comment: Still can you assist on solving this via programming ?

Comment: To Calculate the distance you can use `Point.Subsctract(PointA, PointB).Lenght \ LengthSquared` But to get the points between them you have to specify which is the distance for each point and calculate it by your self.

Comment: @VenelinVasilev you solve the math and apply the solution to your program. There are *infinite* points between any two points. All of them satisfy the same equation. Solve the equation and you can calculate the coordinates for any point

Comment: "i would like to print all the points between those two coordinates" - to what precision?

Comment: All the points in line between.

Comment: @VenelinVasilev there are **infinite points** in between. You can't fake the solution.

Comment: There is a line between those two 3d coordinates. Lets say the distance in that line can be traveled for 5 seconds. Let's print only 5 coordinates for every 1 seconds.

Comment: Between 1 and 2, do you want 1,2 or do you want 1,1.5,2, or do you want 1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2, or do you want 1,1.125, 1.25,1.375,1.5,1.625,1.75,1.875, 2, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the coordinates of the line between two points in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594646/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-the-line-between-two-points-in-python)

Comment: I have added example coordinates.

Comment: I think you have some kind of missunderstanding here.
There are infinite points between two points, as @John ilustrate in the last comment.
Calculate the distance between points with `Point.Substract`, and then divide it by your precision. Then you will get all the points in between.

Comment: Can we calculate the exact point on which it will be at fist second, and then on second two and then so on until second 5. There needs to be only 5 points printed. Not infinite.

Comment: @John the precision can be like this `141.6586f`.

Comment: Divide the distance by (5*numSeconds) to give you pStep, for p0, use the start position. For every subsequent iteration (once every 1/5 of a second) add pStep to the current position. Repeat until you reach the end.

Comment: @John thank you for your assistance. Can you make a complete answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: @VenelinVasilev those are high school questions. Yes, calculate the slopes, intercepts and you got your line. Calculate your speed, and you can find the location for any point in time. Any solution posted here would show just that

Comment: @Nekeniehl what is difference between your example of finding the distance and the one i have described in my question ?

Comment: You're not dividing it by your precision (5*numSeconds) to work out the step (distance between positions) for each 1/5th of a second. That's the difference. I can't really provide a solution because I'm on my phone, but it's not difficult maths, so you should be able to implement the idea very easily. If not, Google "linear interpolation"

Comment: Let's say i can split the distance in 5 steps. That's easy. How can i calculate what is the `x,y,z` from starting point x,y,z to 1/5th step?

Comment: Split it into x, y, and z. Approach each separately. All you need to do is work out the component distance (the x distance, for example), and then divide it.

Comment: Does that means `float deltaX = position1.x - position2.x; float X_on_FirstSecond = deltaX / 5`? Is this what you mean ?

Comment: `float X_onSecondTwo = X_on_FirstSecond * 2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want to do is well described in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799783/slope-of-a-line-in-3d-coordinate-system)

And here is example of code how you can print your values:

```
var mx = pos2.x - pos1.x;
var my = pos2.y - pos1.y;
var mz = pos2.z - pos1.z;
for(var t=0; t < 10; t++) {
    var x = pos1.x + mx * t;
    var y = pos1.y + my * t;
    var z = pos1.z + mz * t;
    //TODO: use you 3D point
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps you forgot 0.1 multiplier like `pos1.x + 0.1 * mx * t;`